# I have some problem with upgrading my chrome driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-chromedriver

I have console error after starting js selenium test:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51114/devtools/browser/ca96d3a3-e745-460c-9029-6102f08b81d9
(node:2632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This 
version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80
```

There is error of incorrect selenium version and chrome driver. I have Chrome 83 version and I want to update chrome driver.
I input 'npm update', 'npm install', but error is present. The chrome driver isn't upgraded using this way. All links from browser search link me to the

```
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
```

I downloaded this archive  for windows 10, but it is console launcher to use chrome driver separate. It isn't update chrome driver in the node modules.
How can I upgrade my chrome driver?

Answer (score 1):

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Use latest chrome driver version and set path correctly